# Many duplicate binaries created in /usr/bin and /bin

Tags: linux, centos

I have a CentOS box that's been up for about a year. It's not got anything hugely important on it, and had a lot of PHP code that I cannot personally vouch for and is fairly old. I realise this is asking for trouble.

I did the things I'm aware of to harden SSH and restrict access via IPTables etc. Today I've noticed a lot of worrying files in /usr/bin/ and /bin/. Lots of what looks like duplicates of binaries, created over a period of a couple of months at the rate of 20 or so a day:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47024 Aug 7 2011 chage;4e3f01f7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47024 Aug 7 2011 chage;4e3f1007
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47024 Aug 8 2011 chage;4e3f1e17
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47024 Aug 8 2011 chage;4e3f2c27
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47024 Aug 8 2011 chage;4e3f3a38
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47024 Aug 8 2011 chage;4e3f4846
```

The other binaries with similar going on are - newgrp, gpasswd, lastlog, dig, usleep and doexec.

The last file date is 8th August so I don't have any logs going back that far. Is anyone able to help me in understanding what has gone on here?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you *why* it's happening, but those numbers after the `;` look a lot like timestamps:

```
4e3f01f7 => Sun Aug  7 17:21:59 2011
4e3f1007 => Sun Aug  7 18:21:59 2011
4e3f1e17 => Sun Aug  7 19:21:59 2011
4e3f2c27 => Sun Aug  7 20:21:59 2011
4e3f3a38 => Sun Aug  7 21:22:00 2011
4e3f4846 => Sun Aug  7 22:21:58 2011
```

(seconds since the epoch in hex). By the fact that they're almost exactly a minute apart, I'd suspect maybe a cron job?

They're also the same size. Maybe you should check if they match with `md5sum`? or if they could even be the same file hardlinked? (check inode number in `stat`).

Comment: They wouldn’t have differing mtimes if they were hardlinked.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Overlooked that earlier when I posted.